# How to delete files which are texted in a text file by batch file?

Tags: batch-file

I am extracting the findstr results as a text file, but i don't know how to delete the files which are extracted as the result by findstr ?

My code is like:

```
@echo off
findstr /s /m "del" "C:\*.*">>"result.txt" 2>nul
```

Now, i want to delete the files which are printed as a name on result.txt in the batch file automatically.

Please Help Me !

Comment: first, take a look to your "result.txt". I'm quite sure, you will be surprised... Are you really sure, you want to delete them all?

Comment: Yes ! I want to delete all files which are printed on result.txt... Please Help Me !

Answer (score 0):

Echoing @Stephan's comment above, make very certain that you want to delete those files. I'm guessing you will get some files you didn't want and might make your system unstable. But in the spirit of answering a question... try something like the following:

```
for /f %%i in (result.txt) do del %%i
```

Comment: OP is offline since your answer. Seems, he didn't believe us. *sigh*

Answer (score 0):

> first, take a look to your "result.txt". I'm quite sure, you will be
>   surprised... Are you really sure, you want to delete them all? – 
>   Stephan 54 mins ago
>   .
>
> Yes ! I want to delete all files which are printed on result.txt...
>   Please Help Me ! –  Ekagra Srivastava 4

Well, you have been warned...

```
for /f "delims=" %%i in (result.txt) do del "%%i"
```